# How to get an element within a different web component?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

When working with JavaScript, it is pretty common to add events to your elements that affect different parts of your DOM. To handle these events, one could use methods like `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName`.
However, when working with web components and the shadow DOM, you cannot access directly an element located in a different component. You have to find a way around the shadow DOM encapsulation. So far, I have been doing it like this:

`document.getElementById("root").shadowRoot.querySelector("#my-element");`

This way I am accessing the main root component of my application, then its shadow DOM, and finally my target element. But what if I need to get an element within a component that is within a component, which is in turn within another component? My code would be a long chain that does not seem very maintainable.

That's why I'm wondering, are there any better ways to do this? Are there any patterns or best practices on this regard?

Comment: `querySelector` follows css like selector style. so it could be `document.querySelector("#root #my-element #my-grandchild-element")`

Comment: Your concept of how to work with Javascript and the DOM does not fit the component approach. Components are encapsulated pieces of software; if you need them to communicate with each other, you have common development patterns like the observer pattern at your disposal. Please give an exaple usecase where one component wants to access another components' internals (which it really *never* should).

Comment: The best way is use to your component events. Most of web component has a way to write your custom event But if your component doesn't have the feature, you can see the `Id` or `class` that your component adds to element and use that to get your element in your component

Comment: @connexo Ok Thanks for the feedback, I shall check on shadow dom. `But Obviously you lack the most basic knowledge about "how to treat others respectfully" which we learn from our parents.` A mature and well educated person knows how to behave in civilized manner and treat others respectfully.I placed it as comment not as answer. A comment is more of a place for discussion. If me or anyone lacks knowledge, we can keep it simple and discuss on it, that's how a community grows, there is no reason to spread hatred. Please delete your comment immediately..

Comment: Rajdeep answer is wrong, **shadowDOM** blocks selectors. Events is the easiest way to create a communication between components; here is a playground JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/qody0u4n/

Comment: @connexo has pointed out correctly that when working with web components, elements of different components should not communicate directly with each other. However, I've researched online and the variety of solutions plus the lack of step by step guides have confused me a lot. I found this great article: https://itnext.io/handling-data-with-web-components-9e7e4a452e6e. It is a good introduction, but at the end, it doesn't really explain how to create an event bus to allow communication between web components. I would highly appreciate any reading recommendations.

Comment: That is a good article; the only way to learn is by doing. Create 2 Elements; make them talk to eachother **by sending Events to ``document``**. An "EventBus" is no magic, it does the same as what you just created.. only with an extra ``class`` to handle communication.